# Odd AC Voltage Reading - 1/4 hp motor

Tags: voltage, motor

I'm trying to troubleshoot an inoperative dishwasher. The dang thing won't fill with water. It's a 2000 vintage machine. No solid state elements anywhere.   I've traced all the circuits. Chased down the obvious potential root causes.

[image: schematic]

Note those X elements are matching points that open or close depending on the location of the control cam.

One thing I'm very baffled by. The controller has a small 1/4 hp motor which spins the control knob 360 degrees at a very slow, geared down rate. My problem is that there are a few elements that are powered in parallel to this motor. With the motor in the circuit I read ~10 vac across the motor, where I'm expecting to see 120 vac.  I'm guessing because of that my solenoid water valve won't work.

I've never worked with AC motors before. Is this normal?  What is odd is that the motor appears to be working just fine. I'm not seeing any excess heat, etc.

Any ideas here?  Is there some sort of crazy internal components that would pull down the voltage under load?

Comment: 1/4 hp motor to rotate the control knob??? that sounds very strange. Also, can't read your diagram - too small. Try drawing one in an online editor of some sort.  Could this be a low voltage motor or DC motor?  Is a transformer present?

Comment: Is the motor turning? If the windings were shorted I would expect bad things - burnt wires, heat, smell, fuses/circuit breakers tripped, etc.

Comment: IF you're sure the water valve solenoid is 120VAC, why not try applying 120VAC directly to it to determine if it opens?

Comment: Some dishwashers have a float in the tub which must be lifted before the cycle can continue (i.e. water is full).  So if the solenoid never opens, and water never goes in, the float never trips, which prevents moving through the cycle, so the motor and associated components don't get full power... grasping at straws here.

Comment: You will be told by Olin shortly that your diagram is an insult to his intelligence. He will vote to close your question, downvote it and throw his dummy on the floor. Before then you MUST do a better job presenting your diagram. The question will be closed regardless as aplliance repair is offtopic but you will/may get better help if you AT LEAST light it well, photograph it well and  upload it at a decent size. Hand drawn can be OK BUT smudgy grey badly lit badly photographed roughly drawn diagrams do not go down well.

Comment: The cam driver will NOT be 1/4 HP. IF it is a mains powered motor then applying mains across it will show if it is OK - if it is a ~=20 VAC motor then applying mains will solve your problems fatally for the motor.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Honestly, that diagram is completely unreadable, contrast or not. You don't have to be an Olin to see that. :)

Comment: DIAL MOTORS are usually 1 Watt gear reduction types. Does Water solenoid activate with jumpers? Is Water float switch stuck open that enables water solenoid? (bottom left corner)  Is 10Vac across the run Cap to motor? if exists...

Comment: @Pipe - You missed out my: "  ...  AT LEAST light it well, photograph it well and upload it at a decent size. ...   smudgy grey badly lit badly photographed roughly drawn diagrams ... " and "Hand drawn can be OK BUT ..." -> ie Yes. there is lots of material for Olin, but he can easily make it vastly better.

Answer (score 1):

### Follow Tony & co

Others have said similar but Tony Stewart's comment nicely sums up things to look at.  Tony said:

Motor,heater and water solenoid are all common, switched to White (neutral) and
Black switched line goes thru timer and float high switch,
Therefore: "no water" is due to

- timer contacts or
- float contacts or
- open solenoid winding or
- seized solenoid from corrosion

Look at what Tony suggested.
Report back.

**___________________________**

### Presentation

What you have drawn is fine enough for your own troubleshooting use (although too too rough and you mislead yourself.

When it comes to involving others a quik redraw can be of much higher quality. THEN photograph it well (lit properly, sharp) and upload it at a size which is readable. If it is above display size the site will downsize the displayed version and give users access to the full uploaded versuion as well.

Your diagram can easily be MUCH better for the purposes of conveying information to others. The diagram below is an example only. First using [**Irfanview**](http://www.Irfanview.com) (free/cheap/good - choose any 3) I cleaned it up to where it was almost readable. I then overlaid SOME of the lines. Smaller line width would be better.  If you draw the diagram lightly bu "square" in one colour you can photograph it, add thicker dark lines then drop out the coloured original.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

sorry to say but i think your motor brushes are bad i looked up 
Its might be time for a new one.

Comment: That does not make sense - if brushes were bad a motor in parallel with other devices and with mains applied by a metallic ontact would show full mains voltage.

Comment: You should say why you think this is true (no reason that I can see IF the motor is mains voltage rated) or edit it or delete it. I have NOT traced through the diagram but motor brushes would only do this if it was in series parallel with other stuff

Comment: motor,heater and water solenoid are all common, switched to White (neutral) and black switched line goes thru timer and float high switch, therefore no water is due to timer contacts or float contacts or open solenoid winding or seized solenoid from corrosion